# Adding db.Model Objects via Function results in <unprintable InterfaceError object>

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Within my flask web-app a user can upload data that will have to be committed to the database using the appropriate model. I created a function that takes in the user's data and returns the appropriate filled in object to be added to the database. My issue is that when I try using a function to create and return this object I get the  error when trying to commit it to database.

I've tested it and the following works;

```
        if form.data_import.data == 'use_template':
            template = equip_model.ReportTemplate.query.filter_by(equip_id=equipment.id).first_or_404()
            keylist = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], template.keylist))
            wb = load_workbook(file)
            #function takes inputs and commits relevant information to correct model
            #output_metric = metric_decider(equipment, keylist, wb, datetime_combo, report)
            
            columns = equip_model.CTMetrics.__table__.columns.keys()
            i=4
            output_metric = equip_model.CTMetrics(
                equip_id = equipment.id,
                report_id = report.id,
                addendum_id = None,
                date_of_test = datetime_combo,
                ctdi_air_body = keylist_value(columns[i+1], keylist, wb),
                ctdi_air_head = keylist_value(columns[i+2], keylist, wb),
                ctdi_w_body = keylist_value(columns[i+3], keylist, wb),
                ctdi_w_head = keylist_value(columns[i+4], keylist, wb),
                mtf_a = keylist_value(columns[i+5], keylist, wb),
                mtf_b = keylist_value(columns[i+6], keylist, wb),
                cnr = keylist_value(columns[i+7], keylist, wb)
                )
            db.session.add(output_metric)
            db.session.commit()
```

Whereas the following does not:

```
if form.data_import.data == 'use_template':
    template = equip_model.ReportTemplate.query.filter_by(equip_id=equipment.id).first_or_404()
    keylist = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], template.keylist))
    wb = load_workbook(file)
    #function takes inputs and commits relevant information to correct model
    output_metric = metric_decider(equipment, keylist, wb, datetime_combo, report)
    db.session.add(output_metric)
    db.session.commit()
```

Code snippet from the function is:

```
def ct_metric_object(equipment_id, keylist, wb, date_of_test, report_id=None, addendum_id=None):
    from app.equipment.models import CTMetrics
    columns = CTMetrics.__table__.columns.keys()
    i = 4 #number of columns not related to metrics
    ct_output = CTMetrics(
        equip_id = equipment_id,
        report_id = report_id,
        addendum_id = addendum_id,
        date_of_test = date_of_test,
        ctdi_air_body = keylist_value(columns[i+1], keylist, wb),
        ctdi_air_head = keylist_value(columns[i+2], keylist, wb),
        ctdi_w_body = keylist_value(columns[i+3], keylist, wb),
        ctdi_w_head = keylist_value(columns[i+4], keylist, wb),
        mtf_a = keylist_value(columns[i+5], keylist, wb),
        mtf_b = keylist_value(columns[i+6], keylist, wb),
        cnr = keylist_value(columns[i+7], keylist, wb)
    )
    return ct_output
```

The above object is pulled from another function:

```
def metric_decider(equipment, keylist, workbook, date_of_test, report = None, addendum = None):
    """
    Takes input Equipment and Report objects to discern the correct Metric model
    to commit data to DB with. Requires keylist and workbook in question as they
    will be passed to committing function.
    """
    category = equipment.category
    print(category)

    metric_commit_map = {
        'General Xray': gen_metric_object,
        'Fluoroscopy': fluoro_metric_object,
        'Mammography': mammo_metric_object,
        'Computed Tomography': ct_metric_object,
        'Nuclear Medicine': placeholder_function,
        'Magnetic Resonance Imaging': placeholder_function,
        'Ultraviolet': placeholder_function,
        'Lasers': placeholder_function
    }
    metric_func = metric_commit_map[category]
    print(metric_func)
    if report is not None:
        output_metric = metric_func(equipment, keylist, workbook, date_of_test, report.id)
        print('Report is not none')
    elif addendum is not None:
        output_metric = metric_func(equipment, keylist, workbook, date_of_test, addendum.id)
        print('Addendum is not none')
    else:
        print('Data added with no accompanying report or addenda.')
        output_metric = metric_func(equipment, keylist, workbook, date_of_test)
    return output_metric
```

The reason I want to be able to call it by function is that there will be multiple views that would use it, so having to write it out wholesale for each instance makes any updates harder.

Any help would be much appreciated - I've only been able to discern that something about the object being returned from a function breaks it but I can't see what. Printing the object before and after the return shows them being identical.

I also see the "sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type" error but it's not clear from the error stack what it's referring to specifically. Is this method just a no-go?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered I had overlooked a key aspect of constructing classes but then found the actual problem had nothing to do with it.

Defining the `__init__(self, x, y,z):` part of each of the classes allowed for more flexible assignment of values than I showed here. It meant I could pass a list of values back to the main view, assign them to the object and add that object to the db session in my main view. This has the added benefit of avoiding concurrent requests if you're using SQLite for your database.

Unfortunately, while this was helpful it turned out my mistake was that a full object instead of the ID of said object was being passed into the final argument and I didn't notice it as it wasn't flagged in the way I was used to in the debugging window.

```
if report is not None:
        output_metric = metric_func(equipment, keylist, workbook, date_of_test, report.id)
        print('Report is not none')
```

Should have been:

```
if report is not None:
        output_metric = metric_func(equipment.id, keylist, workbook, date_of_test, report.id)
        print('Report is not none')
```

A silly mistake but it did end up help me smooth out my project a lot in the end.